# How to make branch B exactly like branch A?

Tags: git

Say I have an existing branch B (if it makes a difference, it's remote).

I also have a branch A (either local or remote). I would like branch B to be exactly like A. If I understand correctly, merge doesn't make the branches identical, there still can be something in branch B that wasn't on branch A and it will remain there after doing `git checkout B` followed by `git merge A`. Do I understand correctly?

Of course, I can just delete branch B and create a new branch B from A. Is that the best way?

**note** just to clarify it: I want to keep branch B alive because of deployment configuration. If I delete and recreate I'll need to do another thing manually for deployment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

git keeps track of the ***history*** of development. Thus, to make a branch exactly like another branch, you just need to:

```
git checkout <branch B>
git reset --hard <branch A>
git push --force origin <branch B>
```

Of course, doing this you will lose the development history that was on branch B.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to rename `branchB`.

```
git branch -m branchB new_name_for_branchB
git branch branchA branchB
```

Now `new_name_for_branchB` refers to the same commit that `branchB` used to, and `branchB` now refers to the same commit as `branchA`. The two branches A and B are still distinct, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this but do you really want to? If B is remote it also means someone else might have it checked out and rewriting will be confusing, at best, for them...

Anyway

```
git checkout B       # get B
git reset --hard A   # change B to be exactly like A
git push --force     # push B to remote, use --force to overwrite B (not normally allowed)
```

Answer (score -1):

the `git reset --hard` as described by others will synch your local branch `A` to the (remote) branch `B` whenever you run it.

If the (remote) branch is a "live branch" (that is, people (possibly other people than you; possibly from multiple localtions/hosts/...) commit to it), it will evolve over time. In order to make your branch "follow" the remote branch through new changes, you might want to set it up as **tracking**.

```
git branch --set-upstream A origin/B
```

then, whenever you `pull` from the remote `origin`, it will (try to) sync your local copy `A`.