# How do I override one branch into another without losing the later's history?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to publish a newer version of my NPM package. The previous version and the current version doesn't have much similarities. We want to override the branch but don't want to lose it's history. How can we accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "override the branch"? What is the current state of your git history? What do you want the end state to be?

Comment: I want the branch from the previous version to have the code of the latest one. But I also want to preserve the history.

Comment: This sounds like a fundamental misunderstanding about what Git does. torek's answer below gives a good explanation. That should help clear up that misunderstanding. I also recommend the book Pro Git which you can get for free online (google it).

Answer (score 2):

History, in any Git repository, is simply the *set of commits in the repository*.  Each commit is numbered, with a big ugly hash ID.  Run `git log`, supply it with a raw commit hash ID, and Git will show you:

- that commit; then
- that commit's *parent* commit (the commit that that commit was made from); then
- the grand-parent commit; then
- the great-grand-parent commit;

and so on.  That "family tree" of commits *is* the history.

A *branch name*, in Git, is simply a way to record *one particular commit hash ID*, so that you do not have to memorize the big ugly random-looking hash ID of that particular commit.  Tag names serve the same purpose: they store the hash ID of one particular commit.  The key difference between a *branch* name and a *tag* name is that a *branch name* is designed to *move*, and in fact, will *move automatically*, by you checking out the branch, then making a *new commit*.

When you are on branch *`B`* and make a *new* commit, the new commit's *parent* commit is, automatically, whatever commit *`B`* used to name.  The new commit is then the commit that branch *`B`* names.

What this means is that if you want the "history" starting from *`B`*, and working backwards through the family tree, to include the previous commits that were on *`B`*, you *must* make the *new* commit come after the currently-last commit on *`B`*.

Meanwhile, note that each commit—each big ugly random-looking hash ID—not only represents the history starting from that point and working backwards.  It also stores a *full snapshot of every file*.  When you use `git log -p` to see *changes*, what you see is the result of Git *comparing* adjacent snapshots: *between this commit's parent, and this commit, the snapshots changed in this way*.

Should you wish one particular *new* commit to store, as its full snapshot, the same snapshot that some other existing commit has, but have as its parent, the same commit that some particular *branch name* already stores, this is easy to achieve.  There are multiple ways to do it.  It is, however, a very unusual thing to *want*.

Should you wish to keep all the commits you have now starting from some branch named *`B`* and working backwards, but use some other *name* for these commits, you can simply *change the name*.  Branch names are not set in stone: any branch can be *renamed* at any time.

One thing to be careful about here, though, is that *every Git repository has its own branch names*.  These names are not *shared* at all.  When you clone a repository, you get all of the other repository's *commits*, and none of its *branches*.  Your Git then creates one *new* branch name in your clone, so that you have one actual branch name.  Your Git finds the *other* commits—the ones that findable by a *branch* name—using your *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/master` or `origin/main`, `origin/develop`, and so on.  These names exist because *your* Git *created* them by *renaming* the other Git's *branch* names.  Each time your Git reaches out to the original (`origin`) Git to get updates, your Git will create or update your own remote-tracking names to correspond to any updates they made to their *branch* names.

What all of this means is that if you change the branch name in some repository, the remote-tracking names in clones of that repository will change—but the *branch* names in clones of that repository *won't*.  Each user will need to do their own branch-name renaming, if they are using that branch name.

Hence, *renaming* the branch is a fine thing to do, but you **must tell all your users / co-workers** about this change, so that they can make the same change to their Git if they choose.  (They don't *have to* do that—there's no reason they can't use the name `zorg` instead of `develop`, for instance—but most people do like to have their own branch names match some other Git's branch names, so that their `zorg` matches their `origin/zorg`, not their `origin/develop`.)

See also [Making two branches identical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36320517/1256452), [How to make branch B exactly like branch A?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33609742/1256452), [git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4911794/1256452), [How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4624357/1256452), and many other instances of this general kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just create a new branch a part of your last branch or hash (of course, of your last branch).

```
git checkout old-branch
git checkout -b new-branch
```

Comment: I guess you meant `checkout -b` rather than `branch -b`?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [torek's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089729/1440565), I want to mention that the question appears to indicate a fundamental misunderstanding of what Git does. Versions should have tags, not branches, once they are released. A version branch can be helpful to prepare for a release but should be merged into the trunk branch and tagged.

Additionally, a tag for a new release should include the history of all previous releases. If Git is used correctly, this just happens automatically. However, a tag for an old release should know nothing about the history of an newer releases. This is the point of "history". It only gives you a view into the past, not the future.